# 2D array/list in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to read in a csv into a 2D array, and I seem to be stuck. Any help with the below code will be appreciated.

```
import sys, csv

rowColumn = [] 
rowColumn.append([])
rowColumn.append([])

with open('filelocation.csv', "r+")  as inputFile:
    fieldnames = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7','col8',]
    reader = csv.reader(inputFile)
        i1=-1
        i2=0
        for row in reader:
            i1=i1+1
            print(row)
            for item in row:
                #store item in 2D list/array
                rowColumn[i1][i2].append(item)#error occurs here
                i2=i1+1
```

Working code:

```
import sys, csv

rowColumn = [] 
rowColumn.append([])
rowColumn.append([])

with open('filelocation.csv', "r+")  as inputFile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputFile)
    i1=-1
    for row in reader:
        i1+=1
        i2=0
        for item in row:
            #store item in 2D list/array
            rowColumn[i1][i2].append(item)
            i2+=1
```

It seems my `i2` variable was located in the wrong spot.

Comment: You should elaborate on your "question". Remember, you posted a "question", yet did not ask any question in your post. Elaborate by stating what is happening, and comparing that to what you want to happen. Then state why you think your code should work, and what you've done to attempt a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the last line: you're making your column number dependent on the row number.  Try something like this instead:

```
    for row in reader:
        i1 += 1
        print(row)
        i2 = 0
        for item in row:
            #store item in 2D list/array
            rowColumn[i1][i2].append(item)
            i2 += 1
```

In case you haven't seen it before,

> i += 1

is equivalent to

> i = i+1

.

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to beat pandas for ease of use:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read CSV file into pandas dataframe df
df = pd.read_csv('filelocation.csv', index_col=False)

# Convert dataframe to python list via a numpy array
python_list = df.values.tolist()
```